# Visualization figures for the grid search optimization steps?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, hyperparameter, optimization

I am using grid search in order to find the best values for the `SVM` parameters (namely `C` and `gamma`). The search is performed in two steps: coarse grid search and finer grid search, as prescribed in this "[A Practical Guide to Support Vector Classification](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/people/Faculty/teaching/726/spring11/svmguide.pdf)" article.

What is not clear to me is `figure 2` and `figure 3` in the aforementioned article: **What are the name/type of these figures and how should they prepared?** One thing that I am not entirely sure about is, as shown in `figure 2`, there are many possible pairs of (`C`, `gamma`) values that produce the same cross-validation rate (i.e. 77.5). So, based on what the best (`C`, `gamma`) in this coarse search step was determined? Is the 77.5, as I think, just a rounded number?

Also, **are there other (better?) figure types** that can be used to visualize the grid search steps?

Comment: This looks like level curves of a function of 2 variables. There exist algorithms to generate these based on values on a grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figures you refer to are contour plots of the hyperparameter response surface, that is the cross-validated performance for each pair of hyperparameters. Visualizing grid search is effectively only useful when you have a pair of hyperparameters, which is rarely the case.

Grid search is generally a poor approach to optimize hyperparameters, though it is still by far the most common approach. Better approaches use metaheuristic or Bayesian solvers and are available in packages like [Optunity](http://docs.optunity.net) and [Hyperopt](http://jaberg.github.io/hyperopt/) .

Here are some examples of SVM hyperparameter optimization using Optunity:

- optimizing the kernel family and its hyperparameterization at once: http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/notebooks/notebooks/sklearn-svc.html
- with contours: http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/notebooks/notebooks/local-optima.html
- optimizing learning algorithm and hyperparameterization: http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/notebooks/notebooks/sklearn-automated-classification.html

Disclaimer: I'm the main developer of Optunity.

Edit: only realize now that you asked about alternative figure types instead of alternative optimization approaches, so I guess part of this answer is not directly relevant. That said, I think the suboptimality of grid search can't be stressed enough.

Answer (score 2):

Fig. 2 and 3 are hyperparameter response surfaces. The diagrams are a level plot for a function of two variables. The authors computed values of the SVM performance at a grid of hyperparamter tuples, and then some plotting algorithm identified level sets.

A common choice of the best hyperparameter tuple is to choose the more strongly regularized model within 1 standard error of the optimum. This is called the 1 standard error rule, and it is described in *[Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)*. This is done to avoid choosing an overly optimistic model.

Another way to display the hyperparameter response surface is a false color diagram, where the color of a particular polygon (usually a rectangle) corresponds to the value of the performance metric at the hyperparameter tuple. But it's only possible to construct these diagrams for very small numbers of hyperparameters, as constructing plots in a larger number of dimensions is impossible.